# Characteristic of an integral domain is 0 (or prime)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

> The characteristic of an integral domain $R$ is $0$ (or prime).

My lecture has not yet covered infinite integral domain but I'll like to understand the proof.

> **Basic fact:**
>
> $R$ is an integral domain so $R$ is a commutative ring with unity (multiplicative inverse = $1$ exists) containing no zero-divisor.

$\space$

> **By definition of a commutative ring:**
>
> - $\left ( R,+ \right )$ is an Abelian group.
> - "$\cdot$" is associative.
> - Distributive law holds.

$\space$

> **Definition (Zero-divisor):**
>
> Let $R$ be a ring. Then an element $a(\neq 0) \in R$ is called a zero-divisor if there exists $b(\neq 0) \in R$ s.t $a\cdot b=0$

By contraposition, since there exists no zero-divisor in the integral domain R, it is true that $a\neq 0$ and there exists no $b\neq 0$.

Can someone take me further? Thanks in advance.

Edit: finite integral domain in lecture is covered

Comment: I don't understand exactly where you are. Specifically, left aside the well-known definitions, I don't understand if the fourth-to-last an third-to-last line are meant to contain a proof of anything or, if so, of what.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose by absurd that the characterist of an integral domain is an integer $n$ not prime. Therefore $n=n_1n_2$  if $e$ is the multiplicative unity of the integral domain then $$ne=(n_1n_2)e= (n_1e)(n_2e)=0$$ but $R$ is an integral domain therefore or $n_1e=0$ or $n_2e=0$ but $n_2,n_1<n$ impossible

Comment: integral domain has unitary multiplicative?